# Converting numpy array of size 2 to 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, numpy-ndarray

suppose i have an each array of size 2

```
Arr1 =([[-4, 1],
       [-3,  1],
       [-2,  1],
       [ 2,  1],
       [ 3,  1],
       [ 4,  1]])
```

How can i add/ append 3rd element, to each array to get the new array/output as:

```
New_Arr1=([[-4,  1, 0],
           [-3,  1, 0],
           [-2,  1, 0],
           [ 2,  1, 0],
           [ 3,  1, 0],
           [ 4,  1, 0]]) ?
```

many thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2):

To append a 0 to all the sub-lists, do:

```
for lst in Arr1:
    lst.append(0)
```

(Note that in your expression for `Arr1`, the outer parentheses have no effect. What you have there is a list of lists.)

Note that this is an in-place change to `Arr1`.  If you want to leave it unmodified and create an entirely separate new list of lists, then you have that in another answer and I won't repeat it, other than to mention that the syntax in Azro's answer assumes Python 3 (which you should be using) but if for any reason you are using Python 2, then use instead

```
new_Arr1 = [lst + [0] for lst in Arr1]
```

---

**Update:** I see that you have tagged numpy, so maybe you actually have a numpy array, although the question is not explicit about this.

If so, you could make a (new, separate) expanded array by doing:

```
New_Arr1 = np.append(Arr1, np.zeros((Arr1.shape[0], 1), dtype=Arr1.dtype), axis=1)
```

(although this certainly does not rule out there being some simpler way).

Comment: you got it, its an numpy array. This solved the query. Thanks alani

Comment: @Sam It is entirely possible that a numpy afficionado will come along and offer a simpler solution, mind you... there often seem to be many ways to do things in numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with a list comprehension, for each array, create a new ones with its values, plus a `0`

```
new_values = [[*val, 0] for val in values]
```